# How to reverse a number without using a n array and also without using any library function?

Tags: java

I want to reverse a number without using array.I want to know how would I save the number.I think for this step I need to also know whether the number is one digit or two digit etc.

Below is my code what I did.

@Edit

I have solved this problem by following method

```
public class ReverseNumber 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    ReverseNumber obj = new ReverseNumber();
    int result = obj.reverse(2199);
    System.out.println(result);
 }

 public int reverse(int num)
 { 
    int rnum1=0;
    for(int i=num;i!=0;)
    {
       rnum1=(rnum1*10)+(i%10);
       i=i/10;
       // write your code here
    }
    return rnum1;
 }
}
```

Comment: School or interview problem?

Comment: Convert the number to a string, then iterate through the characters of the string backwards.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Yes May be Sir.

Comment: @Why there is a negative Vote.I tried to code what I could.

Comment: @Jasonarora How can you say the maximum number of digits will be 2 when in the example code you've got 4?

Comment: @NikG I said May be See carefully.I was not given all test cases at that point.

Comment: @Jasonarora Generally speaking, unless you know for a fact that the input will only have X number of digits, you should assume that the input can be of any length and you should try to come up with a general solution.

Comment: @NikG okay .I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you almost had it! you're only missing the part where you need to multiply `num1` with 10, and the choice of the loop is a bit unlucky:

```
public static int reverse(int num) {
    int input = num;
    int num1 = 0;

    while (input>0) {
        num1 = num1 * 10;
        num1 = num1 + input%10;
        input = input / 10;
    }
    return num1;
}
```

**EDIT:** had a mistake in the implemetation... now it's fixed

Answer (score 3):

@Parker_Halo provided an excellent iterative solution. I am adding here a recursive solution for completeness:

```
public static int reverse(int number, int n) {
    if (number == 0)
        return n;
    return reverse(number / 10, n * 10 + number % 10);
}
```

You would call it like this :

```
int rev = reverse(num, 0);
```

Comment: what would be the number for 103?I get  40 instead of 301.This is how I did.10*3 +10 as I get tens=10  and ones=3.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis I think he misunderstood your question in the comments section ;)

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis this is actually really nice! i'll +1 tomorrow since i have no votes left for today!

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Yes  very nice.Couldn't vote but will vote when i get the privilege.